# replace_na used on a data frame with columns of repeated names

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to replace `NA` values within the columns of a data frame, but since some columns have identical names the function `dplyr::replace_na` replaces the `NA`s only for the first occurrence of each column name.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

namesvec1<-c("John Smith","John Smith Jr df", "Luis Rivera","Ricardo Feliciano  ADE","Huber Villa Gomez 12","Christian Pilares","Luis Rivera","Luis Rivera","Christian Pilares") 
namesvec<-c("John Smith", "Ricardo Feliciano","Christian Pilares","Luis Rivera","John Smith Jr")
namesvec<-sort(namesvec,decreasing = T)
namesfun<-(sapply(namesvec1, function (x)(str_extract(x,sapply(namesvec, function (y)y)))))%>%as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F)

mylist<-list()
for(i in 1:ncol(namesfun)){
  mylist[i]<-"zzz"

}
names(mylist)<-names(namesfun)
replace_na(namesfun,mylist)
```

The result i get is this:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is `dplyr`?

Comment: If you are referring to the replace_na function, then yes.

Comment: Then you should add `library(dplyr)` (same for any other package that the code relies on)  to the example, and add the `dplyr` tag to the existing `r` one.

Comment: You will have to excuse me. I'm new to both R and stackoverflow

Comment: No problem, we all have to start somewhere (usually at the beginning). Give [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) a read, it contains a lot of useful R tricks, particularly for posting on SO.

Comment: Appreciate the guidance :)

Comment: Why do you have duplicate column names? Generally when I have what might end up being duplicate column names, it's a sign that my data is shaped poorly and should be long instead of wide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `purrr`  with `replace_na` to do what you want, when I have a common replacement value for `NA`.

```
library(tidyverse) #for tidyr/purrr/dplyr

map_df(namesfun, ~replace_na(.x, "zzz"))

# A tibble: 5 x 6
  `John Smith` `John Smith Jr df` `Luis Rivera` `Ricardo Feliciano  ADE` `Huber Villa Gomez 12` `Christian Pilares`
  <chr>        <chr>              <chr>         <chr>                    <chr>                  <chr>              
1 zzz          zzz                zzz           Ricardo Feliciano        zzz                    zzz                
2 zzz          zzz                Luis Rivera   zzz                      zzz                    zzz                
3 zzz          John Smith Jr      zzz           zzz                      zzz                    zzz                
4 John Smith   John Smith         zzz           zzz                      zzz                    zzz                
5 zzz          zzz                zzz           zzz                      zzz                    Christian Pilares
```

Comment: I am quite new to R so this might be a stupid question, but why do i get this error when i try to load tidyverse?
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
  call: namespaceExport(ns, exports)
  error: undefined exports: %+%, bgBlack, bgBlue, bgCyan, bgGreen, bgMagenta, bgRed, bgWhite, bgYellow, black, blue, blurred, bold, chr, col_align, col_nchar, col_strsplit, col_substr, col_substring, combine_styles, cyan, drop_style, finish, green, has_color, has_style, hidden............................

Comment: Sounds like an installation error.  Did `install.packages("tidyverse")` complete without error?  If it did error, try restarting your R session and installing it again.

Comment: So, the tidyverse won't install really.I restarted both R and my computer but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Ok.So i updated R, without keeping my existing packages,and I installed langr, and tidyverse from the CRAN and everything works fine.
Thanks a lot btw, the map_df is very useful!

Answer (score 2):

One should never, ever, build data frames with duplicate column names. This is a source of horrendous bugs.

(Apologies for the strong language, but this is an absolute rule that suffers no exception).

Replace `as.data.frame` with `data.frame` (that uses `make.names(unique = TRUE)` internally to guarantee unicity of column names, as long as we keep the default `check.names = TRUE`).

The rest of the code will then work as expected.

---

(Or, possibly, come up with another data frame "shape" or data structure that is better suited to your needs, but this is hard to guess from the question alone).

Comment: So, my columns have repeated names, because I took a column from an existing DF and the rows of it (which had duplicated elements) ended up being my columns (of the new DF).
I am relatively new to R so probably this could be avoided.